# Preload a view in android?

Tags: android

I have a hidden view in android that I show in response to a button press. The first time I show it there's a bit of a delay, and it hitches. After that it shows\hides smoothly.

Is there a way to preload a view so it's ready to be drawn smoothly the first time it's called upon?

Answer (score -1):

Are these "hitches" happening in the emulator or on a real phone?  I find sometimes things chug in the emulator but when I put it onto a phone, it performs fine.